String ArrayList Count first letter occurances and return the char which occurs most
I am trying to solve a problem using nested for loops to be able to first find the first letter of each String in ArrayList names and then need to count the occurnace of each firstletter and return the char value of the letter with most occurances.
I currently have the first letter of each String but am struggling to implement how to count.
public char getMostCommonStartingLetter() {
    char mostCommonLetter = '.';
    int count = 0;

    for (String firstLetter: names)
    {
        //Find first letter
        System.out.println(mostCommonLetter = firstLetter.charAt(0));
    }
    System.out.println(count);
    System.out.println(mostCommonLetter);
    return mostCommonLetter;
}


public char getMostCommonStartingLetter(List<String> names) {
    Map<Character, Integer> letterCount = new HashMap<>();

    // Count occurrences of first letters
    for (String name : names) {
        char firstLetter = name.charAt(0);
        letterCount.put(firstLetter, letterCount.getOrDefault(firstLetter, 0) + 1);
    }

    // Find the most frequent first letter
    char mostFrequentLetter = '\0'; // default value
    int maxCount = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : letterCount.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() > maxCount) {
            mostFrequentLetter = entry.getKey();
            maxCount = entry.getValue();
        }
    }

    return mostFrequentLetter;
}

